# How to update attribute value in feature file each time a program is executed

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, cucumber, bdd

I need help to increment the date of birth and first name value automatically in the feature file after every time the selenium program is executed.
For e.g.

```
firstname | dob
--------- | ------
aaaaa     | 01/01/1970
```

I want the value to be incremented once the selenium program is executed as below.

```
firstname | dob
--------- | ------
aaaab     | 02/01/1970
```

I have been using java language to perform my automation

Comment: Have you tried out any code to increment the counter from `aaaaa` to `aaaab`?

Comment: Not possible via regular flow, you should not do it, feature files are `not` meant to be dynamic, all dynamic data should be in code.